# ps command - list all processes with given command regardless of user

Tags: ps

I want to see a summary of all 'php-fpm' processes, regardless of the user running them.

As I understand from `man ps`, it normally only looks at processes your current user started in a terminal. So `ps -C php-fpm` never yields any results. However the man page seems to suggest that the only way to lift the restrictions is by using something like `ax` but that this **adds all processes** in to the results, **as well as any that match the filters**.

Is the only way to do a big ps then use grep? I'm sure I must have missed something?

I'm using Debian Linux's ps which, according to the man page, confirms to:

> 1. Version 2 of the Single Unix Specification
> 2. The Open Group Technical Standard Base Specifications, Issue 6
> 3. IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition
> 4. X/Open System Interfaces Extension [UP XSI]
> 5. ISO/IEC 9945:2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match the command name *exactly*:

```
ps -fC php-fpm7.0
```

(on Debian 9).

```
ps -C
```

doesn’t restrict itself to the current user’s processes, but it doesn’t match substrings of the command names.

Comment: On mine, the command is shown as `php-fpm: pool foo` yet `ps -fC 'php-fpm: pool foo` does not give any results. But doing as you suggest does work - how did you know the command was not that which is shown in the "command" column?

Comment: `ps -C` matches the `COMMAND` (`-o comm`) column, not the `CMD` column which is what `ps -f` shows. This corresponds to the contents of `/proc/${pid}/comm`, which is usually the name of the binary (`php-fpm7.0` in this case, as revealed by `dpkg -L`).

Answer (score 1):

Use `pgrep` to get a list of PIDs to pass to `ps`:

```
pgrep php-fpm | xargs ps xu
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `pgrep` installed, then

```
pgrep php-fpm
```

would output the process IDs of all commands matching `php-fpm`. To also see the command, add `-l`.

If `php-fpm` is part of the command line and not the actual command itself, add `-f` to the `pgrep` invocation. With `-lf`, `pgrep` would display the full command line used.